# Clean install of ubuntu, is this proccess right?

Tags: installation

I have been using ubuntu from a wubi installation for a year now and I really like it, so I'm considering installing it fresh on a new partition, rather than the ntfs windows one.

I haven't done this again, so I'd like a few tips. Also, on my current install hibernate doesn't work, and I'd really love to have that feature working on my next install.

So here is what I'm planning to do:

1. log on to windows and create a partition on my hard drive.
2. format above partition in an ubuntu friendly file system (should I
   go for ext4 or xfs?)
3. log on to ubuntu and create a bootable usb drive with ubuntu
4. reboot and follow install instructions

Is the above process ok? Am I missing something? Also, wht should I do to get hiberate to work as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just would like to point out that you **should not** create a partition in Windows (because of the wrong partition ID) and you **should not** format the partition in Windows. The most you  can do from Windows is to shrink the existing Windows partition to leave some un-partitioned space on the drive, however, this is not really necessary, because Ubuntu installer can do this for you. So, really, the steps are:

1. create a bootable usb drive with Ubuntu, either from Windows or Ubuntu
2. reboot and follow install instructions (choosing "install alongside existing OS" or manual partitioning)

To make hibernate work, as a minimum, at install time you need to make sure you created a swap partition at least as large as your RAM. As I remember, hibernate has been disabled by default in recent releases of Ubuntu but it can be enabled after installation.

Answer (score 2):

The process you describe seems OK to me but you can speed it up a bit (or make it easier at least).

From Windows you can do all of the following: Create empty space (so without formatting it), download the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD and burn it to a CD/DVD. This will take care of point 1 and 3 without the need of switching OS.

Put the disc in your system, reboot, switch to BIOS to check for 'boot from CD' if you are not sure it already does.

And then follow the Ubuntu installation instructions to install (point 4) in the empty space you created. This will also take care of point 2 so there is not need to pre-format the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to go into your bios and tell it to boot into the drive with your install stuff on it if it doesn't happen automatically. Do this by restarting your computer and hitting some variation of an F key : eg mine is F12, I think, I always forget and just press them all until I get into the bios to be honest.

From the bios you just select the hard drive you want to boot into as the most important one (remember to change it back after the install, if needed)

If that did not work then I would say it was because you did not format it properly

I use FAT. That said, I just install from a usb key using unetbootin (still, I can't see it being a different process once the formatting is done). Formatting a usb is pretty straight forward if you are happy to wipe it clean so you may want to consider that option if you are not sure how to go about things. I have also found it to be useful to keep a loaded usb key handy for when something goes horribly wrong. I can easily to boot into a trial of 'ubuntu to recover my files before having to wipe the system clean and start again afterwards without losing any sweat.